# Batch Failing Output Length Limitation

Tags: java, batch-file, output, stdout

I'm trying to run a batch file through Runtime class in Java.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class TestExec {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

        Process proc;
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            proc = runtime.exec("C:\\test.bat");
            Thread.sleep(5000);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("End of file reached: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("End of file reached: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println("end");
    }
}
```

test.bat

```
echo "It is a test"
echo  "line3"
echo  "line4"
echo  "line5"
echo  "line6"
echo  "line7"
echo  "line8"
echo  "line9"
echo  "line10"
echo  "line11"
echo  "line12"
echo  "line13"
echo  "line14"
echo  "line15"
echo  "line16"
echo  "line17"
echo  "line18"
echo  "line19"
echo  "line20"
echo  "line21"
echo  "line22"
echo  "line23"
echo  "line24"
echo  "line25"
echo  "line26"
echo  "line27"
echo  "line28"
echo  "line29"
echo  "line30"
echo  "line31"
echo  "line32"
echo  "line33"
echo  "line34"
echo  "line35"
echo  "line36"
echo  "line37"
echo  "line38"
echo  "line39"
echo  "line40"
echo  "line41"
echo  "line42"
echo  "line43"
echo  "line44"
echo  "line45"
echo  "line46"
echo  "line47"
echo  "l....."
```

The script is failing, it seems to be that there a limitation on the amount of data that is output. If I use the @echo off at the beginning of the file, the output limitation seems to increase. I also test to run the same batch file command as this `C:\test.bat >> C:\output.txt 2>&1` and it work. Redirecting the output to a .txt make the script ran with no errors. Does anyone has an inside why does this happens? Is there a workaround to increase the amount of data that can be output?

Im running the java executable from the console. Platform is windows 7. 
Thanks.

Outout is this:

```
    C:\app\aime\gc_inst\user_projects\domains\GCDomain>echo "line3" 
"line3"C:\app\aime\gc_inst\user_projects\domains\GCDomain>echo "line4" 
"line4"C:\app\aime\gc_inst\user_projects\domains\GCDomain>echo "line5" 
"line5"C:\app\aime\gc_inst\user_projects\domains\GCDomain>echo "line6" 
"line6"C:\app\aime\gc_inst\user_projects\domains\GCDomain>echo "line7" 
"line7"C:\app\aime\gc_inst\user_projects\domains\GCDomain>echo "line8" "line8"
```

And it just finishes there.

Comment: In wich environment it doesn't work? From command line? Inside your ide? Other?

Comment: What do you mean by failing?  Can you paste the exact error message you see?

Comment: I added the responses to your questions in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try it via cmd.exe.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "C:\\test.bat"});
```

I also normally use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: The problem still persists.